# Looking for a 'cmake clean' command to clear up CMake output

Tags: cmake

Just as `make clean` deletes all the files that a makefile has produced, I would like to do the same with CMake. All too often I find myself manually going through directories removing files like `cmake_install.cmake` and `CMakeCache.txt`, and the `CMakeFiles` folders.

Is there a command like `cmake clean` to remove all these files automatically? Ideally this should follow the recursive structure defined within the current directory's `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: For users of CMake 3.0 and later, you can use `cmake --build <build-dir> --target clean`.

Answer (score 701, accepted):

## CMake 3.X

CMake 3.X offers a 'clean' target.

```
cmake --build C:/foo/build/ --target clean
```

From the CMake docs for 3.0.2:

```
--clean-first  = Build target 'clean' first, then build.
                 (To clean only, use --target 'clean'.)
```

## CMake 2.X

There is no `cmake clean` in CMake version 2.X

I usually build the project in a single folder like "build". So if I want to `make clean`, I can just `rm -rf build`.

The "build" folder in the same directory as the root "CMakeLists.txt" is usually a good choice. To build your project, you simply give cmake the location of the CMakeLists.txt as an argument. For example: `cd <location-of-cmakelists>/build && cmake ..`. (From @ComicSansMS)

Comment: This is called "out of source build" and should be the preferred way to go. It avoids name clashes and the like

Comment: +1 for out-of-source builds. This becomes vital when building multiple architectures. For example, you cannot build both 64bit and 32bit binaries with an in-source build, as this requires two separate CMake cache hierarchies.

Comment: This sounds great. Could you provide some more details on where this folder usually sits relative to your top level CMakeLists, and also how to specify the build location in CMake?

Comment: You can place the folder anywhere you want, but a build folder in the same directory as the root CMakeLists.txt is usually a good choice. To build you simply give cmake the location of the CMakeLists.txt as an argument. For example: `cd <location-of-cmakelists>/build && cmake ..`

Comment: There really ought to be a cmake clean. Everyone who has ever used cmake, even if they are in the habit of doing out of source builds, has accidentally run cmake in the wrong directory and it is a huge pain in the ass to clean up manually.

Comment: @pavon: Any files *generated* by CMake should *not* be under version control. Removing any files from the source directory that are not under version control is easy.

Comment: @DevSolar But the converse is not true; just because a file is not under version control doesn't mean that it is generated by cmake and is safe to blow away. Picking out which unversioned files are work in progress that you need to keep and which are cmake cruft is a pain, especially when much of the cmake files are copies/similarly named to your files.

Comment: Another thing with out-of-source builds is that the generated project might not deal well if the src folder is not below the project folder. E.g. if I generate a VS project in the <location-of-cmakelists>/build, it will compile, but the files are displayed as "external files" and the project cannot generate the structure. Any help for this?

Comment: After becoming really tired for doing the whole "rm -rf build" ... "cmake .." each time I added a solution file, or changed some CMake configuration (e.g. C++17 compilation instead of the default C++11), I started writing the whole thing as a single command line. Use with care ;)


    ```cd .. && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && CC=`which clang` CXX=`which clang++` cmake ..```

Comment: @OlofBjarnason From within the build directory, just do `rm -r *` and your build directory will be cleaned. Then you don't have to re `mkdir build`, although there is the problem that if you accidentally did it from your source directory, you lost all your files :-/. Maybe your solution is better, but you probably don't need the `-f` for `rm`; `rm -r build` should work for many build directories

Comment: I actually removed my source directory once when I meant to remove the build directly. After that, I wrote a script that double checks what is being erased. But really, cmake should just have a write-only mode for cache, it would solve a lot of issues.

Comment: Of course, out-of-source builds are the go-to method for Unix Makefiles, but if you're using another generator such as Eclipse CDT, it prefers you to build in-source. What now? `shopt -s globstar && rm -r **/CMakeCache.txt **/*.cmake **/Makefile **/CMakeFiles`? There really ought to be a `cmake clean`.

Comment: This command may not be safe. A user may put some third-party libraries in the project. If these libraries don't use cmake but have some matched files, this command will delete them.

Comment: I accidentally launched cmake in the source directory instead of the build directory and it spammed it full of the generated files and directories. I really, really wish for an "undo".

Comment: @CJxD , you are awesome and I love your `shopt...` solution which I just aliased to cmake-clean. I would like to suggest adding a `-f` to the `rm` as well to silence any file not found errors printed to STDERR. You really should take all of this and add an answer to the original question, because your solution is by far the best so far.

Comment: That is for Linux, etc. What is the command for Windows, say inside a Windows Docker container?

Comment: If 'cmake clean' is such a bad idea, then it should refuse to do a build in the source directory.

Comment: what if after I remove build directory, and then `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make` -- I get missing function error. If I clone git to another folder and do `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make` -- then it works.
Where does CMake have other leftovers?

Comment: If the `CMakeCache.txt` file is not placed in the `build` directory, then you'll need to delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file as well.  Otherwise, values from this cache file may be used during the next CMake attempt.

Comment: @proski a simple - and fairly reliable - way to avoid accidentally nuking the wrong folder by typing `rm -rf *` is `rm -rf ../build/*` which fails if _build_ isn't the directory being nuked.

Comment: I don't remember what command it was. Maybe a bash completion followed by Enter before I realized what it was. Anyway, I have no desire to through away my scripts now. My point is that it shouldn't be necessary to remove anything just to have it ignored.

Comment: CMake 3.24 does not understand `--target clean` or `--clean-first` on MacOS

Comment: Unsure why this is accepted answer. 3.X does not have `--target` or `--clean-first` on MacOS, or Ubuntu, or Windows...

Comment: cmake's stock clean target fails to remove most of its internal files. The behavior is somehow even worse when using cmake with ninja instead of make.

Answer (score 118):

In these days of Git everywhere, you may forget CMake and use `git clean -d -f -x`, that will remove all files not under source control.

Comment: That `-x` option though. That's an excellent trick of the `git` trade. Though I'd personally still do a dry-run first, `git clean -d -f -x -n`. Every once in awhile I keep a convenience file I use for a project in with the project folder under `git` control, but it's not something I want to share with others so I don't `git add` it to the project. This would blow that kind of file away if I wasn't careful to add a `-e <pattern>` option. On that note, it would be nice if `git` had a `.gitcleanignore` file. :)

Comment: @CivFan you can try using `chattr +i $filename` (needs root permissions, doesn't allow to modify the file after this). This way git won't be able to remove that file even if it tries to do it like `rm -f`.

Comment: That assumes in-source builds, which is to be avoided by itself.

Comment: this was a simple solution (and I have no recollection of what those flags mean, but it's just a dev machine lol).

Comment: Um but what about newly added files which user forgot to `git add`?

Comment: great answer; can you please include the notion of combining flag arguments? i.e. ```git clean -dfx```. This also relies on a good .gitignore btw

Comment: The reason I want a 'make maintainer-clean' is *exactly* because I want to *avoid* deleting files that I created manually but are not in git yet. Such can be (temporary) work files, like test scripts or sources, or crafted files that I need to debug something, or a README that I'm working on but didn't add yet.

Comment: as for `-x`, take extra care. some IDEs save their .files in their "workspace dir", you could lose all your custom settings with that thing >_<

Comment: Downvote, because this is not limited to clearing just the CMake files.

Comment: That is risky, especially when actively debugging gitignore patterns.

Comment: For repos with submodules
```git clean -xfd &&
git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xfd &&
git reset --hard &&
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard```

Comment: and also `git submodule update --init --recursive` to update the submodule

Comment: git clean -xdf -e "my-precious"

Answer (score 95):

[CMake official FAQ](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#cmake-does-not-generate-a-make-distclean-target-why) states:

> Some build trees created with GNU autotools have a "make distclean"
> target that cleans the build and also removes Makefiles and other
> parts of the generated build system. CMake does not generate a "make
> distclean" target because CMakeLists.txt files can run scripts and
> arbitrary commands; CMake has no way of tracking exactly which files
> are generated as part of running CMake. Providing a distclean target
> would give users the false impression that it would work as expected.
> (CMake does generate a "make clean" target to remove files generated
> by the compiler and linker.)
>
> A "make distclean" target is only
> necessary if the user performs an in-source build. CMake supports
> in-source builds, but we strongly encourage users to adopt the notion
> of an out-of-source build. Using a build tree that is separate from
> the source tree will prevent CMake from generating any files in the
> source tree. Because CMake does not change the source tree, there is
> no need for a distclean target. One can start a fresh build by
> deleting the build tree or creating a separate build tree.

Comment: Originally, as introduced and used by GNU autotools, the 'distclean' target is intended to make the source tree ready to tar up and create a tar distribution. Such a tar file users can download and untar and then run 'configure' and 'make' *without* needing the autotools (aclocal, automake, autoconf, etc)

If we extrapolate that to cmake then a 'make distclean' would leave us with a clean source that can be built without having cmake installed. However, this doesn't work when the generator was a single-target generator (as the 'make' target is), because configuration with cmake happens while

Comment: ... running cmake. Making a distribution that cannot be configured, does not even do platform tests etc, is useless. Hence there does not exist 'distclean' target for cmake. cmake is *required* to exist on the machine of the end-user.

Comment: `we strongly encourage users to adopt the notion of an out-of-source build` -- shame they made it the default behavior then.  (Seriously, having the default behavior be something you discourage users from doing is a silly design decision.)

Answer (score 60):

I googled it for like half an hour and the only useful thing I came up with was invoking the `find` utility:

```
# Find and then delete all files under current directory (.) that:
#  1. contains "cmake" (case-&insensitive) in its path (wholename)
#  2. name is not CMakeLists.txt
find . -iwholename '*cmake*' -not -name CMakeLists.txt -delete
```

Also, be sure to invoke `make clean` (or whatever CMake generator you're using) **before** that.

:)

Comment: I would recommend against using this approach if the directory you are working in is under version control: when I tried this approach with svn it removed some of the repositories working files.

Comment: Lovely! I'm going to create an alias for this in bashrc or bash_profile. @Yuri: It'd be nice to add a small explanation of what all those parameters mean.

Comment: There might other files matching *cmake* so this really is not a universal approach. This should do: rm -rf CMakeFiles; rm -rf CMakeCache.txt; rm -rf cmake_install.cmake;

Comment: I would remove -exec rm -rf {} \+ and just use -delete.

Comment: Downvoted, since this command can potentially delete some user files. I do prefer honza_p command, not really longer, simpler and less risky.

Comment: I agree with @AdrienDescamps

Comment: @AdrienDescamps: except it still leaves cmake-related junk in subdirectories. I was doing `rm -rf CMakeFiles ; rm -rf */CMakeFiles ; rm -rf */*/CMakeFiles ; rm -rf */*/*/CMakeFiles` and still wasn't done...

Comment: If someone executes this command in my source tree, I will shoot them.

Comment: This is a bad advise - deleting *randomly* all files with *cmake* in it would (for example) destroy my project (if I didn't have a backup).

Comment: `find` is non-portable for COMSPEC Windows users. `-not` is non-portable for non-Linux/non-POSIX users. `rm` is non-portable for COMSPEC Windows users. Also not futureproof. Also ignores make and ninja files. Also, incredible risk of accidentally deleting a file just because it is named similarly to cmake.

Answer (score 41):

You can use something like:

```
add_custom_target(clean-cmake-files
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P clean-all.cmake
)

// clean-all.cmake
set(cmake_generated ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeCache.txt
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Makefile
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles
)

foreach(file ${cmake_generated})

  if (EXISTS ${file})
     file(REMOVE_RECURSE ${file})
  endif()

endforeach(file)
```

I usually create a "make clean-all" command adding a call to "make clean" to the previous example:

```
add_custom_target(clean-all
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} clean
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P clean-all.cmake
)
```

Don't try to add the "clean" target as a dependence:

```
add_custom_target(clean-all
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P clean-all.cmake
   DEPENDS clean
)
```

Because "clean" isn't a real target in CMake and this doesn't work.

Moreover, you should not use this "clean-cmake-files" as dependence of anything:

```
add_custom_target(clean-all
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} clean
   DEPENDS clean-cmake-files
)
```

Because, if you do that, all CMake files will be erased before clean-all is complete, and make will throw you an error searching "CMakeFiles/clean-all.dir/build.make". In consequence, you can not use the clean-all command before "anything" in any context:

```
add_custom_target(clean-all
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} clean
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P clean-all.cmake
)
```

That doesn't work either.

Comment: Is there a way to fill cmake_generated automatically? Perhaps, combining this with the answer of yuri.makarevich? Currently, this won't remove files in the subdirectories of ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}.

Comment: Does not work for Ninja or Visual studio. I wouldn't recommend such an approach.

Comment: Nice idea but this does not remove `CMakeCache.txt` and not help me too, but I found this similar way to update variables in every build, so no need to remove `CMakeCache.txt`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159371/how-to-create-a-cmake-variable-that-takes-a-default-value-unless-explicitly-over/53159688#53159688

Answer (score 39):

Simply issuing `rm CMakeCache.txt` works for me too.

Comment: Only deleting related variables in CMakeCache.txt works for me too.

Comment: Deleting CMakeCache.txt and then running 'cmake --build /build-path' causes 'Error: could not load cache'.

Comment: @nenchev you need to run `cmake /build-path` again.

Comment: @Samaursa cmake --build reruns cmake when needed, this method breaks the build directory and cmake complains. My answer further down tells you to delete the CMakeFiles/ directory, which causes a clean rebuild and cmake to automatically rerun.

Comment: @nenchev when you manually delete the cache, you have to run `cmake /build-path` again as it expects a cache file to exist when the `CMakeFiles` directory does. Of course, if you delete the `CMakeFiles` directory, then `CMake --build` will know to run `CMake`.

One of the reasons this is important to know (and I wish there was a `CMake --cleancache` or similar) is because in large builds, deleting `CMakeFiles` can trigger a time consuming generate (and a search for compilers, which on Windows takes an unusually long time). Deleting the `CMakeCache.txt` and running `CMake` again is faster.

Comment: @Samaursa My point is that deleting the CMakeCache.txt leaves the build directory in a messed up state, requiring you to rerun cmake /build-path. I obviously know that CMakeCache is expected, and the point I'm making is that deleting just that file forces you to explicitly rerun cmake, after which if you run the build, it doesn't actually rebuild everything (clean build). Maybe I misunderstood, but a clean build to me is like any other build system, recreate build files, recompile sources.

Comment: @nenchev I see what you mean and I agree.

Comment: Really the best answer so far.

Comment: Not, if you have several caches in different subdirs.

Answer (score 28):

Starting with **CMake 3.24**, there exists the `--fresh` command line option which rebuilds the entire build tree every time:

> `--fresh`
>
> New in version 3.24.
>
> Perform a fresh configuration of the build tree. This removes any
> existing CMakeCache.txt file and associated CMakeFiles/ directory, and
> recreates them from scratch.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options

Comment: That doesn't begin to delete all the different junk files that a typical cmake project generates.

Comment: @mcandre No it doesn't, but it doesn't matter. The build tree gets regenerated including the cache. So the build output should be unaffected regardless of junk files that may or may not be there.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe it's a little outdated, but since this is the first hit when you google `cmake clean`, I will add this:

Since you can start a build in the build dir with a specified target with

`cmake --build . --target xyz`

you can of course run

`cmake --build . --target clean`

to run the `clean` target in the generated build files.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that the out-of-source build is the best answer. But for the times when you just must do an in-source build, I have written a Python script available [here](https://raw.github.com/tschutter/homefiles/master/bin/cmake-clean), which:

1. Runs "make clean"
2. Removes specific CMake-generated files in the top-level directory such as CMakeCache.txt
3. For each subdirectory that contains a CMakeFiles directory, it removes CMakeFiles, Makefile, cmake_install.cmake.
4. Removes all empty subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks for that. I would like to add a line to your script that silences `make` when there is no `Makefile` present due to a prior clean (i.e., makes this script idempotent). Just add the line (properly spaced): `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory,'Makefile')):` right before line 24: `args = [` and of course indent the rest of the function body after the line just added. This will only perform a `make ... clean` if a `Makefile` is present in the current directory being cleaned. Otherwise, the script is perfect!

Comment: _"But for the times when you just must do an in-source build"_ When exactly are those times, though? I hope they're few and far between, these days, and that whenever you encounter one, you file a bug with the maintainers asking them to fix their build tooling. Any project that uses CMake, at least, needs to support out-of-source builds, otherwise their code is a chore to use with `ExternalProject` (requires `BUILD_IN_SOURCE`, implied goat sacrifice), and I'm not even sure it's possible with `FetchContent` since it lacks a similar option.

Answer (score 8):

It's funny to see this question gets so many attentions and complicated solutions, which indeed shows a pain to not have a clean method with cmake.

Well, you can definitely `cd build_work` to do you work, then do a `rm -rf *` when you need to clean. However, `rm -rf *` is a dangerous command given that many people are often not aware which dir they are in.

If you `cd ..`, `rm -rf build_work` and then `mkdir build_work` and then `cd build_work`, that's just too much typing.

So a good solution is to just stay out of the build folder and tell cmake the path:
to configure: `cmake -B build_work`
to build: `cmake --build build_work`
to install: `cmake --install build_work`
to clean: `rm -rf build_work`
to recreate build folder: you don't even need `mkdir build_work`, just configure it with `cmake -B build_work`.

Answer (score 7):

In the case where you pass `-D` parameters into CMake when generating the build files and don't want to delete the entire build/ directory:

Simply delete the CMakeFiles/ directory inside your build directory.

```
rm -rf CMakeFiles
cmake --build .
```

This causes CMake to rerun, and build system files are regenerated. Your build will also start from scratch.

Comment: It is not enough. CMakeCache.txt has to be deleted as well (like for found libs).

Comment: `rm` is not portable; it fails in Command Prompt. Yes, PowerShell, WSL, and Cygwin-like environments can provide a workaround. But I like my stuff to work more portably than that. Using rez as a workaround. https://github.com/mcandre/rez

Answer (score 7):

## CMake 3.X

CMake 3.0 and above offers a 'clean' target. This removes any artifacts like object files, library files, executables, generated files, etc.

```
cmake --build C:/foo/build/ --target clean
```

You can also clean the build, then run the build. In 1 command.

```
cmake --build C:/foo/build --clean-first
```

However, this WON'T cleanup things like the `CMakeCache.txt` or the associated `CMakeFiles/` directory. Which you may want to do. You just have to delete the build folder.

```
# Just delete the build folder
rm C:/foo/build -rf

# You can also just let git delete the build folder as well
git clean -d -f -x
```

## CMake 3.24

Now in CMake 3.24 you can perform a fresh `configuration` of the build tree. This removes any existing CMakeCache.txt file and associated CMakeFiles/ directory, and recreates them from scratch.

Generally you want to do this when:

- You want to clear cached variable in CMakeCache.txt
- You want to change compilers
- Any other operations related to CMake caching

```
cmake -B C:/foo/build --fresh
```

Answer (score 5):

try to use:
cmake --clean-first path-of-CMakeLists.txt-file -B output-dir

--clean-first: Build target clean first, then build.
(To clean only, use --target clean.)

Comment: That screen shot shows **text** only. Yet you take a screen shot of it, breaking the answer for anybody who comes here with a screenreader. Please drop that picture, and do a copy/paste of text, and spend the 1 minute to properly format that input.

Comment: what do you mean by use --target clean.

$ cmake --target clean
CMake Error: Unknown argument --target
CMake Error: Run 'cmake --help' for all supported options.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, out-of-source builds are the go-to method for Unix Makefiles, but if you're using another generator such as Eclipse CDT, it prefers you to build in-source. In which case, you'll need to purge the CMake files manually. Try this:

```
find . -name 'CMakeCache.txt' -o -name '*.cmake' -o -name 'Makefile' -o -name 'CMakeFiles' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Or if you've enabled globstar with `shopt -s globstar`, try this less disgusting approach instead:

```
rm -rf **/CMakeCache.txt **/*.cmake **/Makefile **/CMakeFiles
```

Comment: My choice yesterday was cloning repo to a new folder, update CMakeLists.txt to build from subfolder `build`. It took a little longer time than those commands but I had to do it one time only :)

Answer (score 4):

--fresh (cmake version 3.24 or later)

Can be used to remove the previous cache file and recreate the build tree.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that I found recently is to combine the out-of-source build concept with a Makefile wrapper.

In my top-level CMakeLists.txt file, I include the following to prevent in-source builds:

```
if ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there. You may need to remove CMakeCache.txt." )
endif()
```

Then, I create a top-level Makefile, and include the following:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CMake project wrapper Makefile ----------------------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

SHELL := /bin/bash
RM    := rm -rf
MKDIR := mkdir -p

all: ./build/Makefile
    @ $(MAKE) -C build

./build/Makefile:
    @  ($(MKDIR) build > /dev/null)
    @  (cd build > /dev/null 2>&1 && cmake ..)

distclean:
    @  ($(MKDIR) build > /dev/null)
    @  (cd build > /dev/null 2>&1 && cmake .. > /dev/null 2>&1)
    @- $(MAKE) --silent -C build clean || true
    @- $(RM) ./build/Makefile
    @- $(RM) ./build/src
    @- $(RM) ./build/test
    @- $(RM) ./build/CMake*
    @- $(RM) ./build/cmake.*
    @- $(RM) ./build/*.cmake
    @- $(RM) ./build/*.txt

ifeq ($(findstring distclean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
    $(MAKECMDGOALS): ./build/Makefile
    @ $(MAKE) -C build $(MAKECMDGOALS)
endif
```

The default target `all` is called by typing `make`, and invokes the target `./build/Makefile`.

The first thing the target `./build/Makefile` does is to create the `build` directory using `$(MKDIR)`, which is a variable for `mkdir -p`. The directory `build` is where we will perform our out-of-source build. We provide the argument `-p` to ensure that `mkdir` does not scream at us for trying to create a directory that may already exist.

The second thing the target `./build/Makefile` does is to change directories to the `build` directory and invoke `cmake`.

Back to the `all` target, we invoke `$(MAKE) -C build`, where `$(MAKE)` is a Makefile variable automatically generated for `make`. `make -C` changes the directory before doing anything. Therefore, using `$(MAKE) -C build` is equivalent to doing `cd build; make`.

To summarize, calling this Makefile wrapper with `make all` or `make` is equivalent to doing:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

The target `distclean` invokes `cmake ..`, then `make -C build clean`, and finally, removes all contents from the `build` directory. I believe this is exactly what you requested in your question.

The last piece of the Makefile evaluates if the user-provided target is or is not `distclean`. If not, it will change directories to `build` before invoking it. This is very powerful because the user can type, for example, `make clean`, and the Makefile will transform that into an equivalent of `cd build; make clean`.

In conclusion, this Makefile wrapper, in combination with a mandatory out-of-source build CMake configuration, make it so that the user never has to interact with the command `cmake`. This solution also provides an elegant method to remove all CMake output files from the `build` directory.

P.S. In the Makefile, we use the prefix `@` to suppress the output from a shell command, and the prefix `@-` to ignore errors from a shell command. When using `rm` as part of the `distclean` target, the command will return an error if the files do not exist (they may have been deleted already using the command line with `rm -rf build`, or they were never generated in the first place). This return error will force our Makefile to exit. We use the prefix `@-` to prevent that. It is acceptable if a file was removed already; we want our Makefile to keep going and remove the rest.

Another thing to note: This Makefile may not work if you use a variable number of CMake variables to build your project, for example, `cmake .. -DSOMEBUILDSUSETHIS:STRING="foo" -DSOMEOTHERBUILDSUSETHISTOO:STRING="bar"`. This Makefile assumes you invoke CMake in a consistent way, either by typing `cmake ..` or by providing `cmake` a consistent number of arguments (that you can include in your Makefile).

Finally, credit where credit is due. This Makefile wrapper was adapted from the Makefile provided by the [C++ Application Project Template](http://code.google.com/p/cpp-project-template/).

Comment: I suggest to never use a `Makefile` as a meta-builder. It is really disturbing and error prone. If you want to do that, write a script (eg `build.sh`)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following shell script for such purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fld in $(find -name "CMakeLists.txt" -printf '%h ')
do
    for cmakefile in CMakeCache.txt cmake_install.cmake CTestTestfile.cmake CMakeFiles Makefile
    do
        rm -rfv $fld/$cmakefile
    done
done
```

If you are using Windows then use Cygwin for this script.

Answer (score 2):

## Clear the cmake build output:

### Command line:

```
$ rm -rf [folder that you builded the project]/
$ cmake --build .
```

### Cmake:

```
cmake --build . --target clean
```

Answer (score 1):

cmake --build /path/to/build --target clean

Answer (score 0):

To simplify cleaning when using "out of source" build (i.e. you build in the `build` directory), I use the following script:

```
$ cat ~/bin/cmake-clean-build
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d ../build ]; then
    cd ..
    rm -rf build
    mkdir build
    cd build
else
    echo "build directory DOES NOT exist"
fi
```

Every time you need to clean up, you should source this script from the `build` directory:

```
. cmake-clean-build
```

Comment: Nice and safe. As I you may have the build directory opened in file manager, I suggest replacing the `cd .. ; rm ; mkdir ; cd` sequence with `cd .. ; rm -rf build/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Shame that CMake does not properly support user-defined additions to the built-in `clean` target.

After much trial & error, partly using ideas mentioned here by other, I arrived at the following pragmatic solution.

Since globbing/wildcards is done during the `cmake` run, not when doing `make clean`, can add to the `clean` target only those files and directories for which the path name is known in advance, e.g.:

```
set_property(
  DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  APPEND
  PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES
      doc/ CMakeDoxyfile.in install_manifest.txt _CPack_Packages
)
```

For the rest, I resorted to a new `clean_all` target, which can be defined more flexibly and can invoke the `clean` target, e.g.:

```
add_custom_target(clean_all
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL} clean
   COMMAND find . -name "*.o" -o regex "./project-.*" | xargs rm
   COMMAND rm CMakeCache.txt
   # after the following being executed, cannot call this target again:
   COMMAND find . -name "*.cmake" -o -name Makefile | xargs rm
   COMMAND find . -name CMakeFiles | xargs rm -r  # need to do this separately
   VERBATIM
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you run

```
cmake .
```

it will regenerate the CMake files. Which is necessary if you add a new file to a source folder that is selected by *.cc, for example.

While this isn't a "clean" per se, it does "clean" up the CMake files by regenerating the caches.

Comment: It does not clean wrt. the compilation state: If 500 out of 1200 files have been compiled, after "cmake ." it will just continue with the last 700 files.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty old, but if you completely remove the cmake-build-debug folder, when you compile using cmake it should automatically create a new cmake-build-debug folder with everything you need. Works especially well in CLion.

Answer (score -2):

If you have custom defines and want to save them before cleaning, run the following in your build directory:

```
sed -ne '/variable specified on the command line/{n;s/.*/-D \0 \\/;p}' CMakeCache.txt
```

Then create a new build directory (or remove the old build directory and recreate it) and finally run `cmake` with the arguments you'll get with the script above.

Answer (score -2):

`cmake` mostly cooks a `Makefile`, one could add `rm` to the **clean PHONY**.

For example,

```
[root@localhost hello]# ls
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  CMakeLists.txt  hello  Makefile  test
[root@localhost hello]# vi Makefile
clean:
        $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
        rm   -rf   *.o   *~   .depend   .*.cmd   *.mod    *.ko   *.mod.c   .tmp_versions *.symvers *.d *.markers *.order   CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  CMakeCache.txt  Makefile
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I use. It's wrapped in a function, It's cross platform and it demonstrated how to find matching filenames or folder names, in case you wanted to make any easy adjustments. This function runs every time I build my scripts and has worked flawlessly for my needs.

```
function(DELETE_CACHE)
    if(CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)
        execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c for /r %%i in (CMakeCache.*) do del "%%i" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
        execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c for /d /r %%i in (*CMakeFiles*) do rd /s /q "%%i" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
    else()
        execute_process(COMMAND find . -name "CMakeCache.*" -delete WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
        execute_process(COMMAND "rm -rf `find . -type d -name CMakeFiles`" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
    endif()
endfunction()
```

Answer (score -3):

I used [zsxwing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680420/looking-for-a-cmake-clean-command-to-clear-up-cmake-output/9680493#9680493) successfully to solve the following problem:

I have source that I build on multiple hosts (on a Raspberry Pi Linux board, on a VMware Linux virtual machine, etc.)

I have a Bash script that creates temporary directories based on the hostname of the machine like this:

```
# Get hostname to use as part of directory names
HOST_NAME=`uname -n`

# Create a temporary directory for cmake files so they don't
# end up all mixed up with the source.

TMP_DIR="cmake.tmp.$HOSTNAME"

if [ ! -e $TMP_DIR ] ; then
  echo "Creating directory for cmake tmp files : $TMP_DIR"
  mkdir $TMP_DIR
else
  echo "Reusing cmake tmp dir : $TMP_DIR"
fi

# Create makefiles with CMake
#
# Note: switch to the temporary dir and build parent 
#       which is a way of making cmake tmp files stay
#       out of the way.
#
# Note 2: to clean up cmake files, it is OK to
#        "rm -rf" the temporary directories

echo
echo Creating Makefiles with cmake ...

cd $TMP_DIR

cmake ..

# Run makefile (in temporary directory)

echo
echo Starting build ...

make
```

Answer (score -9):

Create a temporary build directory, for example, `build_cmake`. Hence all your build files will be inside this folder.

Then in your main CMake file add the below command.

```
add_custom_target(clean-all
    rm -rf *
)
```

Hence while compiling do

```
cmake ..
```

And to clean do:

```
make clean-all
```

Comment: nice way to remove all your project if someone accidentally will build in-source instead of out-of-source

Comment: yes. this method should be used only with "out of source build"

Comment: Terrible recommendation. Should not exist as answer.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum agree