# cmake create a shared object

Tags: build, cmake, shared-libraries

I have three files:

lib.c lib.h => They should be built as a .so file 
client.c    => This should be built as an executable. 
 
Inside the client.c I include the lib.h file so as to get the declarations of the functions defined under lib.c

Can someone tell me the exact CMakeLists file that I should be using so that the source area is uncluttered with Cmake's temporary files and the binaries and the libraries (.dlls in case of windows I believe) generated in separate build and binary directories ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cmake builds on separate build directories by default (I did not test this example):

```
PROJECT(myproject)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

SET(mylibSRCS lib.c)
SET(myprogSRCS client.c)

ADD_LIBRARY(mylib ${mylibSRCS})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(myprog ${myprogSRCS})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myprog mylib)
```

You do:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Everything would be under build.

Update: As mentioned by @chryss below, if you want the .so file to be generated, the command should be:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED ${mylibSRCS})
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the build always in a new directory without executing these shell commands ? I googled but could not find any useful links.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143062/getting-cmake-to-build-out-of-source-without-wrapping-scripts/11144109#11144109

Comment: Yes.  You can  `mkdir build & cd build & cmake .. & make`.  If you need to super-clean your repository, just delete the build directory.  This isolates the generated stuff from your original sources.

Comment: `ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED ${mylibSRCS})`, as mentioned by @chryss below.

Answer (score 17):

This solution will not create a `.so` file, but a cmake equivalent for further inclusion with cmake.
I am searching for a solution with will provide the equivalent to this:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,plugin_lib.so.1 -o plugin_lib.so plugin_lib.o
```

Which will generate a `plugin_lib.so` that can be loaded dynamically with dlopen at runtime.

The solution is missing the "SHARED" option like so:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED ${mylibSRCS})
```