# Change CMake build Directory

Tags: cmake, out-of-source

**I would like to change the Working Directory of cmake**. For example currently when I run the cmake from *c/* directory where is the *CMakeLists.txt*, this will be the created directories and files:

```
c/CMakeFiles/
c/implementation/
c/cmake_install
// ...
```

**This is really ugly** and our application is *Cross-platform*, so this is not good. Currently I use Cmake from *c/build* directory like this:

```
cmake .. -Dparam=qnx-debug
cmake .. -Dparam=linux-release
```

So based on the parameters (and if I run cmake from *c/*) I wanna create a directory structure like this:

```
c/build/qnx-debug/CMakeFiles
c/build/qnx-debug/implementation
// ...
// or when I want build for linux
c/build/linux-release/CMakeFiles
c/build/linux-release/implementation
// ...
```

Is this possible with cmake or only with bash?

Regards,
Krisztian

Comment: Create a subdirectory `build/<foo>-release` and execute there `cmake ../..` and you  get what you want?!

Comment: Currently I use this, but that is the one what I want to replace:
mkdir -p ./build/$1; cd build/$1; cmake ../.. -Dparam=$1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting cmake to build out of source without wrapping scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143062/getting-cmake-to-build-out-of-source-without-wrapping-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like the answer is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143062/getting-cmake-to-build-out-of-source-without-wrapping-scripts), but you can make the command a little cleaner by using the undocumented `-H` and `-B` arguments to cmake. They specify the directories of the source and the build files, respectively.

For what it's worth, I've used [premake](http://premake.github.io/) and it does support out-of-source builds without wrappers.