# Can I define a project directory?

Tags: directory, cmake

When I run `Cmake` I transmit a directory with a `CMakeLists.txt`, but project build in working directory.

Can I transmit a destination directory?

P.S I can't to wrtite

> cd .\build
>
> cmake ..

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your question is a duplicate to [Getting cmake to build out of source without wrapping scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143062/getting-cmake-to-build-out-of-source-without-wrapping-scripts)

Comment: @Florian, you are right, thank you