# cmake remove files/directories has no effect

Tags: cmake

This question is based on the following [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143062/getting-cmake-to-build-out-of-source-without-wrapping-scripts) to disable in-source build: while the following setup disable in-source build, it left garbage like "CMakeCache.txt" and "CMakeFiles/". I tried to use `file()` command to remove it, but it appears no effect. Any idea?

```
if ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    file(REMOVE CMakeCache.txt)
    message( FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed.)
endif()
```

Comment: Probably, CMake creates `CMakeCache.txt` even after failure in configuration. So removing this file during configuration has no effect.

Comment: I think you are right, I tested this with a fake file, and it works as expected. Wonder if there is a solution here ...

Comment: "garbage" is not the right term. There is a reason that in-source builds are discouraged. You kind of misuse the tool, then don't be surprised it behaves as it likes.