# How do I clean a build folder in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a project with a "source" folder and a "build" folder. Every time I change something in CMake that is requiring reconfiguration, I have to manually delete contents of the build folder. I was curious to know if there is something like this:

```
cmake clean
```

Is it possible to delete all the content within a build folder in CMake? If yes, how?

Comment: @ruslo: I actually meant a way to put such kind of commands within CMakeLists.txt file and then run something like "cmake clean" from the shell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a 'cmake clean' command to clear up cmake output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680420/looking-for-a-cmake-clean-command-to-clear-up-cmake-output)

Comment: @Kamiccolo: I have checked the link you gave and sure it is, thanks.

Comment: That isn't a duplicate.  There is a difference between producing the build files and actually building the resulting project.  This asked about the configuration which generates the build files and the other link posted by kamiccolo is about cleaning the result of a build.  That's not the same thing.