# cmake rm -rf build best practice

Tags: cmake

I have seen that cmake does not have `cmake clean` 
from [Looking for a 'cmake clean' command to clear up cmake output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9680420/6329006), When using cmake as to the following situation:

1. source file change
2. CMakeLists.txt change
3. add new file or directory
4. subdirectory(cmake) change

and do on.

We may need rebuild the project, lots of people will do `rm -rf *` in the build directory to clear the last build, and then `cmake ..` `make` to rebuild the project.This maybe very slow if the project is very big.And in some situation there is no need, just do make is enough.

So my question is when should we do `rm -rf *` in the build directory and then rebuild the project and when not ? Is there any best practice?

Answer (score 3):

> When should we do `rm -rf *`?

#### Main usage

When **something goes unexpectedly**. This includes:

- "I have library *FOO* installed, but CMake cannot find it",
- "I have changed file *BAR*, but CMake doesn't rebuilt its dependencies",
- and so on

#### Other usages

Technically, removing build directory usually helps in clearing the CMake cache. (So, the same effect can be achieved by `rm CMakeCache.txt` command). This is mainly needed for **re-find** things like libraries or header files. Examples:

- "I have changed environment settings, so CMake needs to find *another* library"
- "I have changed CMake variables before `find_package` call, so CMake needs to find *another* library"