# How to not use /usr/local/lib after uninstalling self build package?

Tags: linux, makefile, path, filesystems, ubuntu-20.04

Initially, I had `pcl-1.10` in `/usr/`(installed using `sudo apt install libpcl-dev`). Then I self-built `pcl-1.12` in `/usr/local/` for some reason. Now I uninstalled `pcl-1.12` using `sudo make uninstall` and wanted to use the default `pcl-1.10`. But when I compiled my project, the error message showed

```
$ colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Starting >>> lidarslam_msgs
Starting >>> ndt_omp_ros2
--- stderr: ndt_omp_ros2                                                                           
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libpcl_surface.so', needed by 'align'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/align.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ndt_omp_ros2 [0.16s, exited with code 2]
```

It seems that the PATH stills points to the `/usr/local/lib` even if I uninstalled the package. Is there a way I can reset PATH to the global package path? For this case, I believe the `pcl-1.10`'s `libpcl_surface.so` is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_outofcore.so` .

I am working on ROS2 and compiling the CMakeList.txt using `colcon`. So I can't modify the makefile. I assume it is a PATH problem.

A way is to use symlink to link all the .so file in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to `/usr/local/lib` but I found it kind of stupid...

Comment: Try to clean the files generated by `cmake` or remove and re-create the whole build directory. Maybe see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9680420/10622916

Comment: Yes, it works after remove all build directory. Thanks, Bodo!